# Get referrer string for Universal Link?

Tags: ios, ios9, http-referer, referer, referrerurl

I implemented Universal Links in our iOS 9 app and they work by calling a method in **AppDelegate.swift**, in which I get an `NSUserActvity` with an URL attached to it.

Is there a way to get the (HTTP-) referer? I need to know on which website the user has tapped the link that opened the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use NSUserActivity > referrerURL instance property. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity/2875762-referrerurl.

Comment: This seems to work! Thanks Art. Note to others: The property is not available before iOS 11.

Comment: This only works when redirecting from a website from a broswer? Is there a solution when coming from another app? Like Source Application in open url method.

Comment: This does not seem to work. The property is there, but it is always `nil`, whether coming from a website or another app.

Comment: @chadmoone from my experience it works for some web pages and doesn't work for others at the same time. Eg - I was able to get `referrerURL` from Safari Gmail where I put my universal link, but doing so in Safari Yahoo Mail, Safari Telegram - gives me `nil`. Also was able to get it from Facebook and Twitter web pages. Have no clue how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to get the referrer.
An Apple employee made that pretty clear on the developer forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65423

They say that the only way to get some kind of referrer would be to append it to the URL. Maybe take a look Google's campaign tracking URLs (utm_...).

Answer (score 1):

I found another interesting solution if you need to support iOS 9 and 10 - https://appmetrica.yandex.com/blog/referrer-based-tracking-dlya-ios-tochnaya-atributsiya-dlya-lyubogo-istochnika-trafika.

Since iOS 11 I guess can be used NSUserActivity > referrerURL.

In short:

- SFSafariViewController uses the same cookies as Safari app.
- You can open invisible SFSafariViewController inside your app.
- If your site contains some cookie - use Universal Link to pass it back to the app.

Though it requires to implement something like tracking link on your site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as said above you can get the referrer url through an `NSUserActivity` via the `referrerURL`.

But you may found `nil` values for this `referrerURL` depending the **referrer policy** established by the website you used for the redirection.

To understand we need to have a look at the **Referrer policies**. These policies are used to secure the way of how the referrer urls are passed from a website A to another website B.

For example in some cases, website A don't want that website B be able to get the details parameters of the referrer URL so they can defined a particular type of policy. Sometimes they can completely make the referrer url `null` to website B by setting the `no-referrer` policy type for example.

This policy is defined into an HTTP header named `Referrer policy` and currently by default have the following type: `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`. You can check actually what policy is used by the source website by opening the inspector console > network > select the website url and check the `Referrer policy` HTTP header.

You can have a look at the different kinds of policies and what rules they apply [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#strict-origin-when-cross-origin_2)

For example in our case, we were not able to get the referrer URL using the safari top banner that allows users to be redirected into our app. But using a specific link such as a link from Twitter or Slack or whatever, was providing a referrer URL.